# Помогите понять, почему не работает код

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

В чем может быть проблема неработающего кода на сайте http://total-helper.ru/pervaya-stranica/
Брали отсюда http://triumphsimulator.summoners-of-aradal.ru/ru/

Comment: проблема в том, что Ваш js код немного кривоват. И если бы открыли консоль разработчика, то там как минимум сразу подсказывает о 551 строке. И там невооруженным глазом видна проблемка, хотя нет, "ПРОБЛЕМИЩЕ"

Answer (score 1):

Некорректная структура html и ошибки в js.
Например здесь видно что вставлены теги html в код js, что не даёт ему нормально работать.
Нужно посмотреть код страницы и удалить лишние тэги.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть много валидаторов, заходи туда, заводи url страници или копируй код страницы и вставляй там. Они показывают где ошибки.
Мне показали от 25 до 50 ошибок на твоей странице...

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftotal-helper.ru%2Fpervaya-stranica%2F

https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator

Просмотр кода твоей страницы:
view-source:http://total-helper.ru/pervaya-stranica/

Comment: Современные браузеры автоматически вставляют закрывающийся тэг.

Comment: Закрывают, но не открывают. Здесь проблема в другом - js не парсится.

Comment: Ну там вообще не ясно откуда этот `<p>` посреди скрипта, то ли намеренно автором добавлен, то ли как он там оказался.

Comment: Скорее всего автоподстановка при копировании ;)